# Size of an ImageView in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

Is not possible to get the size of an ImageView in a widget app(AppWidgetProvider)? I want to put a Bitmap inside this ImageView and I need to know the size.

Comment: Why do you need to know the size exactly? As far as I know an image is resized automatically according to the dimensions of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know the size exactly? As far as I know an image is resized automatically according to the dimensions of the widget.

But if you want to know the size, I think you can do this best with [getMaxHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getMaxHeight%28%29) and [getMaxWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getMaxWidth%28%29)